# How to compare and subtract elements in nested list to generate a new list

Tags: list-manipulation

I have list of lists like this one:
`list={{1, 9, 4, 7, 2}, {1, 4, 7, 1, 8}, {0, 5, 7, 2, 9}}`
where every nested list have 5 elements.

I want to compare the third, fourth and fifth elements of each nested list and do the subtraction: the largest number minus the smallest number. The result should create a new list.

In my example, it should work like this:
in the first nested list `{1, 9, 4, 7, 2}` the largest value between the third, fourth and fifth elements is `7` and the smallest `2`, subtraction 7-2=5. So 5 will be the first element in the new list with results. I want to do it with every nested list in my list of list. 
For my example, the result will be:
`result={5,7,7}`

The problem is that I don't know how to do it. It's not just comparing the elements between nested lists or extracting specific elements from the lists (because I want to compare and subtract them first, then get the result). Please help!

Comment: Isn't the result supposed to be `{5, 7, 7}`?

Comment: i want to compare only the third, fourth and fifth elements from each nested list, so: 7-2=5, 8-7=1, 9-7=2

Comment: Does `(Max[#[[3;;5]]] - Min[#[[3;;5]]] &) /@ list` work for you?

Comment: also I do think the result should be `{5, 7, 7}`, as `1` is the smallest element among the 3rd, 4th, and 5th elements of the second list, and `2` is the smallest among those elements in the last list

Comment: omg you're right, my fault! i'll change it

Comment: now it turns out that I can't even count, all the more reason I need help

Comment: `Subtract @@ Reverse@MinMax@#[[3 ;; 5]] &  /@  list`

Comment: @thorimur it seems to work well, thank you!

Comment: @LouisB it works too, thank you!